# windows silverlight app stuck on one page

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, navigation

In my windows phone app I am doing a scanning process, wherever I am in the app, when the scan button is pressed on my bottom appbar, I navigate to my scan page, known as **ScanView.xaml**.

**Problem**: 
I have overridden onnavigatedTo method of scanView to initiate scanning screen.

When I press back button while I am on the scanning screen It goes back to ScanView.xaml and hence onnavigatedTo method is again called and my scanning screen again appears.

What I want to do is, when I press back button while on scanning screen it should navigate directly back to my mainpage.xaml

P.S : I have tried overriding the backbutton handler, but it is still not working.

**Here is my code.**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {   
        //this method is invoked as soon as we are navited to the ScanView         
        Scanning();  
    }
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Why usev use ScanView.xaml and not navigating directly to the scanning page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove ScanView.xaml from the navigation stack (it is the item at the top of the stack) when navigated to the scanning page.